# Javascript: Basic for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I just completed some form of a competency exam for a programming school, and I got every question correct except this, although it appears really quite easy, yet I couldn't get it. Any ideas?

Observe the code below.

```
var x = [1,5,7,13];
for(i=0; i < x.length; i++)
{
x[i] = x[3-i] + 2;
}
```

Once the program is done, what would be in x?

```
a [3,7,9,15]
b [15,9,11,3]
c [15,9,7,3]
d [15,9,11,17]
```

Comment: Have you broken out pencil and paper for this?

Comment: You could run this in a brower's dev tool console and find out.

Comment: I've tried just writing it out and plugging the numbers in, yet I foolishly don't get any of the options listed in the multiple choice.

Comment: In Chrome - press F12. Select "console" tab. Paste there ``var x = [1,5,7,13];
for(i=0; i < x.length; i++)
{
x[i] = x[3-i] + 2;
}
console.log(x);``. Press enter. Win.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is d

first loop

x[0] = 13 + 2 = 15

second loop

x[1] = 7 + 2 = 9

third loop

x[2] = 9 + 2 = 11

fourth loop

x[3] = 15 + 2 = 17

x = {15, 9, 11, 17}

Answer (score 0):

To figure this out, you'll have to understand that `x[]` is used to refer to a specific index of the array. For example:

`var x = [5,6,7];`

In this case, `x[0]` would be equal to `5`, assuming a 0-index based array.

Knowing this, let's break down your loop. We'll start by filling in the *variable name* instead of the *variable value* step by step, to leave out confusion of following variables in your head.

```
var x = [1,5,7,13];
for(0=0; 0 < x.length; 0++)
{
x[0] = x[3-0] + 2;
}
```

For the first iteration, everything starts to become a little clearer as you can tell that now it's setting `x[0]` (the first value in the array) to equal `x[3-0]` (which would be `x[3]`, which in turn would be `13` due to the 0-index array), plus 2. `13 + 2 = 15`. The first number is 15.

```
var x = [1,5,7,13];
for(1=1; 1 < x.length; 1++)
{
x[1] = x[3-1] + 2;
}
```

Let's try one more! `x[3-1]` is the same as `x[2]` which is `7`; `7 + 2 = 9`. Your second number is `9`.

Following the same logic you can see how the loop functions and understand how it's referencing the array's values.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is that you're updating the same array you're reading from as you go through it. *(Note: generally I'd consider this bad practice and I've seen a lot of programmers fall into this trap - it's very easy to misunderstand the code)*.

First thing to realize is that `x[3-i]` basically reads the opposite end of the current index. To be more generic, it should really have been `x[(x.length-1)-i]` but the `3` is hardcoded in this case.

Now, the first round is easy: `13+2 = 15`. 13 because the opposite end of the first element is the last element:

```
x = [15,5,7,13]
      ▲      │ this+2
      └──────┘
```

In the second round we replace `5` with `7+2 = 9`:

```
x = [15,9,7,13]
        ▲ │ this+2
        └─┘
```

In the third round we find ourselves doing something not initially obvious. Instead of replacing `7` with `5+2` we replace it with `9+2` instead because we've already replaced 5 with 9:

```
x = [15,9,11,13]
        │ ▲
 this+2 └─┘
```

Now finally we replace the last element with `15+2` using the same reasoning above:

```
x = [15,9,11,17]
      │       ▲
      └───────┘ 
     this+2
```